# AVRCP for Windows phone 8?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-phone-8, multimedia, avrcp

I have a project for multimedia player running on WP8. Does WP8 SDK supports AVRCP that user can control playback from Bluetooth device? What APIs or events I should use to receive control events? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a consumer perspective WP7 OS [supports](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2449475?wa=wsignin1.0) BT-AVRCP 1.3 and so does WP8 OS. Based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207007%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Bluetoothprofilessupportedinwp8) the BT-AVRCP 1.4 profile is supported for WP8.

From a developer perspective BT-SPP is supported for direct developer reads & writes. I'm not sure if WP8 can successfully open a BT-AVRCP socket, so go ahead and try to open a socket to one and see what happens.

If you're just trying to play Audio on a Bluetooth headset, use the plain-old WP7/WP8 media playback classes and use the new WP8 [AudioRoutingManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207273%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to force output on bluetooth headset.

```
AudioRoutingManager.SetAudioEndpoint(AudioRoutingEndpoint.Bluetooth)
```

Comment: Thanks! I am acutally using MediaPlayer APIs to play/pause songs in Media library. What I need is for users to control playback functionality through BT device. The audio actually routed correctly without doing additional things. Do you mean opening socket to get commands (play/pause/ff/fr) from BT device? Can you please give more info? Thanks again!

Comment: I haven't tried a BT-AVRCP socket. Potentially you might be able to open one and send commands. Here's an example of opening up a BT-SPP socket to Sphero @ http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What's_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Bluetooth:_Phone_to_device  . And here's an example of a BT-SPP socket to Mindwave Mobile headset @ http://metroeeg.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Standalone&referringTitle=Home

Comment: AVRCP is layered over L2CAP and not over RFCOMM. The sockets in WP8 use RFCOMM apparently only. (http://www.alanjmcf.me.uk/comms/bluetooth/Bluetooth%20Profiles%20and%2032feet.NET.html#_Toc266869894)